# New Line Not Working on Windows Notepad (SAP ABAP)

Tags: line, new-operator, abap

Tried CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>CR_LF, CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>NEWLINE.
Both work on NotePad++ and Excel 2010 but not on Notepad.

Any hints?

Comment: Please describe in detail your system landscape, what you did and what you wanted to achieve anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I made a wrong definition of CR_LF. Please check my blog for the detailed explanation.

http://www.dsun.us/node/60

I made a similar mistake yesterday. I think I need to take a break now.